# Breakpoints causing slowdown for Python Code

Tags: python

I have noticed that adding breakpoints to python programs cause a large performance difference (up to 100 times), even from adding a single breakpoint at the end of the program.

For example the program

```
import timeit
a = timeit.default_timer()
for i in range(10**7):
    pass
print(timeit.default_timer() - a)
print("Done")
```

runs in about 0.3 seconds on my machine without any breakpoints. However adding a single breakpoint on line 6 (print("Done")) causes the runtime to increase to over 19 seconds (over 60 times slowdown). This was tested using VSCode with WSL:Ubuntu over Windows 11 and Python 3.8.10.

Is this expected behavior?

Thanks very much!

Comment: ...what do you think a breakpoint is for? What type of breakpoint are you setting, and what are you doing with it?

Comment: @Chris When I say it takes 19 seconds I mean that it takes 19 seconds to get to the breakpoint (not time spent on the breakpoint). The breakpoint is a regular (unconditional) breakpoint. I want to be able to review the state of the program without it exiting. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot expect arbitrary code to perform the same when running under a debugger as when it is not. By their very nature, debuggers need to do a lot more than simply execute the code.

Comment: @Chris The increased time occurs only when I add a breakpoint before running the code. For example if I start the code with a debugger and then add a breakpoint while the code is running then it still takes less than a second.

Comment: I'm not sure what optimizations VSCode has for running without any breakpoints, but they likely exist. My point is that you cannot expect production-speed execution when running this way (in a debugger, a debug build, without optimizations compiled in, etc.) Why does it matter? When debugging you should be thinking about _how_ the code is executing, with a focus on correctness. Raw speed is largely unimportant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally run the python code in command prompt by calling file and do editing in notepad++. I tried with breakpoint and without breakpoint, there is no difference in both the situations and coming as ~0.47 second. I think the issue what you might facing is due to IDE response time.

C:\Users\drarc\OneDrive\Desktop\Issue>python
Python 3.10.2 (tags/v3.10.2:a58ebcc, Jan 17 2022, 14:12:15) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

C:\Users\drarc\OneDrive\Desktop\Issue>breakpoint.py
0.46787520015984774
Done